# TFS 2015 Deploy website to multiple machines with a load balancer

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015, release-management

I'm using TFS 2015 to build and deploy my websites.
I have multipe websites and i need to deploy then to multiple machines that have a NLB.

So the steps are:

1 - Stop NLB on machine 1

2 - Deploy files

3 - Start NLB on machine 1

4 - Repeat to all machines.

Is there a way of doing this without have to configure this steps to each machine?

Its possible to have a machine group and apply the steps to each one?

Thanks

Comment: Which task did you use for Stop and Start NLB step?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a custom task called **Tokenizer** in the workflow of the release. It tokenizes the variable in web.config which then can be transformed. Tokenizer needs the initial values of the custom variable in a specific format.

> To install the tokenizer you first need node.js with npm packager
>   installed on our machine. Follow this process to install and use
>   Tokenizer.
>
> Download and install node.js on your machine if it is not present. It
>   also installs npm package loader.
>
> Download tokenizer from https://github.com/openalm/VSOtasks. It comes
>   as a .zip file. Unzip it.
>
> Open command prompt and change directory to the folder
>   “Tokenizer\x.x.x” in the unzipped folder.
>
> From that folder run the command npm install -g tfx-cli to install the
>   command line tool that can upload the tokenizer task.

[image]
After using this you will be albe to write the environment specific configuration file when you are deploying to different environments. More detail steps and tutorials. Please take a look at this blog from MSDN:  [Deploy to multiple environments with appropriate configurations](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mvpawardprogram/2016/05/17/microsoft-release-management-deploy-to-multiple-environments-with-appropriate-configurations/)

---

Update

For "rolling deploy", this can't be achieved for now. No this option and task in web base release  management. You may have to apply the steps to each machine. If you really need this feature, you can add it in [uservoice](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services) of VSTS, TFS admin and PM will kindly review your suggestion.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i already use the tokenizer, what i want to do is Rolling Deploy.

Comment: Like, Drain NLB on machine 1, deploy on machine 1 and then start NLB on machine 1.

Comment: And then do for the next machine, and the next, and so on.
Do this without having to set every step for diferent machines.

Comment: This can't be achieved for now. No this option and task in web base release  management. You may have to apply the steps to each machine.

Comment: Ok, I will apply for every machine. Thanks

Comment: If it helps, could you mark it as an answer, thanks! Any update about the rolling deploy in TFS will let you know.